# No main manifest attribute in jar error despite manifest specifying main class

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar

So I've written a rather small app in java and once it worked I wanted to "properly" build it using eclipse built-in gradle. Just when I try to `java -jar` the jar-file I get the "no main manifest attribute" error and I just can't understand why.

I specified the main class in `build.gradle`, the manifest extracted from jar contains the correct main class, it works when I specify main class with -cp flag... I am out of ideas

The extracted manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
MainClass: gameHelper.problemSolving.Main
Implementation-Title: GameHelper
Implementation-Version: 1.0
```

The build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'application'
}

mainClassName = 'gameHelper.problemSolving.Main'

jar {
    archivesBaseName    = 'GameHelper'
    archiveVersion      = '1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'MainClass': 'gameHelper.problemSolving.Main',
            'Implementation-Title': 'GameHelper',
            'Implementation-Version': '1.0'
        )
    }
}
```

File structure:

```
src
 |--main
 |   |--java
 |       |--gameHelper
 |           |--io
 |           |   |--FileIO.java
 |           |--model
 |           |   |--Hero.java
 |           |--problemSolving
 |               |--Main.java
 |--gradle
 |   |-- <gradle files>
 |--build.gradle
 |--gradlew
 |--gradlew.bat
 |--settings.gradle
```

Comment: it must be `Main-Class` instead of `MainClass` (similar to the other 2 attributes) -- see the [JAR File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#main-attributes)

Comment: @user85421 thank you! Works now. But pretty embarrassing... dumb mistake